# Want multiple records instead of one for using when condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in DWH with only one row for one of the ID but when I am using the update statement for the COLUMN_1 like

```
UPDATE [T_TABLE]
SET COLUMN_1=case when ([Partner] = 'SAP' and 
                           ((Technology = 'SAP S/4HANA Cloud' or Technology = 'SAP S/4HANA Hosted' or Technology = 'SAP Cloud Platform' or
                             Technology = 'SAP Business Technology Platform' ) and 
                             
                             (Segment = 'Automotive'))) then  'SAP Auto Cloud'

when ([Partner] = 'SAP' and  ([Technology] = 'SAP S/4HANA ONPREM' or
                                                [Technology]  = 'SAP S/4HANA Cloud'or  
                                            [Technology]  = 'SAP S/4HANA Hosted'or 
                                               [Technology]  = 'SAP Digital Manufacturing/Supply Chain' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP Integrated Business Planning (IBP)' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP Ariba' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP Concur' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP Fieldglass' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP SuccessFactors' or
                                              [Technology]  = 'SAP Qualtrics')) then 'SAP Intelligent Suite & Industry Cloud' 

end
```

So for Partner as 'SAP' and Technology as 'SAP S/4HANA Hosted' I want two rows for the single ID one will show me COLUMN_1 as 'SAP Intelligent Suite & Industry Cloud' and other row will show as 'SAP Auto Cloud'. Right now it is not happening because when first condition satisfies it keeps the COLUMN_1 as 'SAP Auto Cloud' and then moves to the end. So is there any other alternative of when condition that I can use here?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here. It reads like you're saying that you want 2 rows in a column on a single row, but a row can only contain one row... Also, you do you that `IN` exist right? `Technology IN ('SAP S/4HANA Cloud','SAP S/4HANA Hosted','SAP Cloud Platform')` is far more readable than `(Technology = 'SAP S/4HANA Cloud' or Technology = 'SAP S/4HANA Hosted' or Technology = 'SAP Cloud Platform' or Technology = 'SAP Business Technology Platform' )`

Comment: @Larnu Yes I want two rows for one ID if the condition is Partner as 'SAP' and Technology as 'SAP S/4HANA Hosted' .But while using WHEN I am getting only one row of COLUMN_1 as 'SAP Auto Cloud'  as if the first condition satisfies then after that it moves to the end.
So what should be the alternative here??

Comment: Also, a `CASE` will only return the **first** expression than returns true. The expression `CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 WHEN A = 1 AND B = 2 THEN 2 END` will *never* return `2` because the first boolean expression is would have resolved to true. In such a scenario, you would need to put the most restrictive boolean expression first: `CASE WHEN A = 1 AND B = 2 THEN 2 WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 END`. Then `2` can be returned.

Comment: *"Yes I want two rows for one ID if the condition is Partner "* Impossible, a single row cannot contain many rows. You can't `UPDATE` a row and have one of the columns in the row become 2 rows; that's not how a relational database works. You need to normalise your data. Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.